# how do I use $x variable across different functions inside a class?

Tags: php

Iam learning PHP, I am having a class inside which I wanna share one variable across multiple functions as below, but unfortunately iam getting error as:

```
<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting T_FUNCTION on line <b>5</b><br />
```

So, how do I use $x variable across different functions inside a class, sorry if its a noob query.

**Here is the code:**

```
<?php


class A{

$x = 10;

    function a(){
        global $x;
        echo $x;
    }



    function b(){
        global $x;
        echo $x;
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: you can declare it as `public $x=10;` and you can access `$this->x` in each method

Comment: @Sundar if I use public, then $x variable would be visible to any class, right? So using variable $x  as 'Private' would be correct, right?

Comment: if you don't want to access through object in outside the call you can declare it as `private`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the property of a non-static member, you can refer to `$this` as the class.

```
$this->x
```

So for your code:

```
class A{
    //clarity
    public $x = 10;

    public function a(){
       echo $this->x;
    }

    public function b(){

        echo $this->x;
    }
}

$class = new A;
echo $class->a(); //results in 10
echo $class->b(); //results in 10
```

Comment: if I use public, then $x variable would be visible to any class, right? So using variable $x  as 'Private' would be correct, right?

Comment: Public - any class can use it. private - only this class can use it. protected - any class that implements this class can use it. Depends on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

User $this to access a class variable also use return in function a() becuase class convention function called automatically as you instantiate a class (because it treated as a constructor of class A - same name for class and function)

```
class A{

    var $x = 10;

    function a(){

        return $this->x;
    }

    function b(){

        echo $this->x;
    }

}
$obj = new A();
echo $obj->a();
?>
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] your answer to give an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272), because they don't teach the solution.

Answer (score 0):

you should use `$this` to access this variable within the class.

you code would be this:

```
<?php
class A{

public $x = 10; // make the scope of variable as public

    function a(){
        return $this->x; // use this variable as "$this->x" to access everywhere in that class
    }

    function b(){
       return $this->x;
    }
}

/*
In order to access you can use
*/
$myClass = new A;
echo $myClass->a(); //the output will be 10
echo $myClass->b(); //the output will be 10
?>
```